# What is the nucleon axial charge?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, charge, quantum-chromodynamics

Can someone point me to a short definition of what the [nucleon axial charge](http://www.google.com/search?q=nucleon+axial+charge) is?

Answer (score 3):

``Axial charge'' refers to the (isovector) axial coupling constant $g_A$ of the nucleon
$$
\langle p|A_\mu^a|p\rangle = g_A \bar{u}(p)\gamma_\mu\gamma_5\tau^a u(p)
$$
where $A_\mu^a=\bar{\psi}\gamma_\mu\gamma_5\tau^a\psi$ is the QCD axial current, $|p\rangle$ is a nucleon state with momentum $p$, $u(p)$ is a free nucleon spinor, and $\tau^a$ is an isospin Pauli matrix. Experimentally (from beta decay), $g_A=1.26$.

Comment: What is $\tau$?

Comment: Isospin matrix.